# Installing tensorflow on Linux

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to install Tensorflow on Linux. Unfortunately, I can barely use Ubuntu.

I followed the page "https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/get_started/os_setup.html#create-the-pip-package-and-install"

and I am stuck at "Create the pip package and install" part. 
When I typed "`bazel build -c opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package`" the terminal gives me below

```
No command 'bazel' found, did you mean:
 Command 'babel' from package 'openbabel' (universe)
 Command 'babel' from package 'babel-1.4.0' (universe)
bazel: command not found
```

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 8):

You need to install "Bazel", google's homegrown build tool for building the sources. You can get it here: [Installing Bazel](http://bazel.io/docs/install.html)

But if you are just getting started with this do you even need to bother with building from the source code?

Maybe you should try just installing the binaries using pip with a one line command as described here: [pip installation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/get_started/os_setup.html#pip-installation)

```
# Ubuntu/Linux 64-bit, CPU only:
$ sudo pip install --upgrade   https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.7.1-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl

# Ubuntu/Linux 64-bit, GPU enabled:
$ sudo pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow-0.7.1-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```

Answer (score 6):

I have faced similar problem. Then I realized that I forgot to set up the environment as follows:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin"
```

Comment: @winhowes: it solved the problem for me and I wanted to share it. I would like to know the reason behing getting a negative vote for this answer. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't give it a negative vote. I just added some code highlighting

Comment: @winhowes thanks for your answer. Perhaps for someone it did not work.

Comment: This solved my problem when I was trying to install SyntaxNet on OSX Yosemite. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a small bash script that sets up Ubuntu to be ready to run TensorFlow. It may be of use to you:

https://github.com/jasonmayes/Tensor-Flow-on-Google-Compute-Engine

From the script here you can see how I install bazel, however that also has a number of dependencies :-)

```
wget https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases/download/0.1.5/bazel-0.1.5-installer-linux-x86_64.sh -O bazel-0.1.5-installer-linux-x86_64.sh
chmod +x bazel-0.1.5-installer-linux-x86_64.sh
sudo ./bazel-0.1.5-installer-linux-x86_64.sh --user
rm bazel-0.1.5-installer-linux-x86_64.sh
sudo chown $USER:$USER ~/.cache/bazel/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can  install tensorflow from "pip install" directly or you can install it from source. If you choose to install from source code. First you should install the bazel, it is a tool to build tensorflow from source.

Answer (score 0):

Just an update:

```bash
# Ubuntu/Linux 64-bit, CPU only, Python 2.7
$ export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.9.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl

# Ubuntu/Linux 64-bit, GPU enabled, Python 2.7
# Requires CUDA toolkit 7.5 and CuDNN v4. For other versions, see "Install from sources" below.
$ export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow-0.9.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl

# Mac OS X, CPU only, Python 2.7:
$ export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.9.0-py2-none-any.whl

# Ubuntu/Linux 64-bit, CPU only, Python 3.4
$ export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.9.0-cp34-cp34m-linux_x86_64.whl

# Ubuntu/Linux 64-bit, GPU enabled, Python 3.4
# Requires CUDA toolkit 7.5 and CuDNN v4. For other versions, see "Install from sources" below.
$ export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow-0.9.0-cp34-cp34m-linux_x86_64.whl

# Ubuntu/Linux 64-bit, CPU only, Python 3.5
$ export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.9.0-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl

# Ubuntu/Linux 64-bit, GPU enabled, Python 3.5
# Requires CUDA toolkit 7.5 and CuDNN v4. For other versions, see "Install from sources" below.
$ export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow-0.9.0-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl

# Mac OS X, CPU only, Python 3.4 or 3.5:
$ export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/tensorflow-0.9.0-py3-none-any.whl
Install TensorFlow:

# Python 2
$ sudo pip install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL

# Python 3
$ sudo pip3 install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL
```

More details on this:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/get_started/os_setup.md

Answer (score 0):

If your system has pip installed, it is an easy task. If not, install pip using:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev
```

You can run Tensorflow using the system GPU or CPU. Also note that, as of now, tensorflow only supports Nvidia GPU. If you have an Nvidia GPU, [reading this link](http://www.nvidia.com/object/gpu-accelerated-applications-tensorflow-installation.html) would be better as it gives good level of clarity.

For CPU installation run-

1. `export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.10.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl`

   This sets the url where the binaries reside. It changes from time to time, so make sure you use the appropriate url. Next, run-
2. `sudo pip install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL`